# How to mark java code such that it's not compiled

Tags: java

I'm wondering if there if a Java equivalent for C's

```
#if 0
... Some Code ...
#endif
```

Which can be used around code blocks we don't want to compile. Adding block quotes:

```
/*
... Some Code ...
*/
```

also has the same effect, but the problem is, we have to ensure there are no single line comments

```
// some comment
```

in the block.

Comment: why do you have to ensure there are no `//` comments? -- The `//` inside a block comment is still legal syntax. also there is no reason you should be using `#if 0 ...` in C. that's what block comments are for

Comment: For the second part, if I understand this correctly - Can't the block quotes be used for single line comments?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526113/java-conditional-compilation-how-to-prevent-code-chunks-to-be-compiled

Comment: Apologies, I seem to be mistaken. We don't have to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no pre-processor directives in Java. Your best choice is commenting out code.

Answer (score 26):

`static final` fields can be use for conditional compilation.

```
static final boolean DEBUG = false;

if (DEBUG) {
  some code ....
}
```

`some code` will be removed by the compiler.

It is also possible to use the `assert` keyword to enable and disable some part of the code. Use `java -ea: ..` to control if the code should be enabled or disable. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/assert.html

Comment: Does this only work if the static final is a boolean? Will using `DEBUG` as an integer work?

Comment: @Pacerier No it works for `static final int`s also but not `enum`s. I checked with decompiler, enums remain as is, but yes, `int`s can reference other final `int`s. Also `switch-case` with `int`s don't do the magic - i.e., plain `if...else if...` ladders

This should have been the answer!

Comment: @zeropoint, However does the specs guarantee that this would indeed be compile-time?

Comment: Just checked if it changes the actual bytecode. It does, the whole part in if is missing if the statement is always false.

Comment: _the whole part in if is missing_ The if clause is removed as well right?

Comment: @DQQpy Yes, the if statement is also removed.

Answer (score 3):

There are several solutions:

1. Use a preprocessor - I think that it will work with the standard CPP. There were some Java specific proprocessors as jappo and [java+](http://virtualschool.edu/java+/) that you can try
2. Replace the #if 0 with a true if:

   if(false) {
     code
   }

The condition can be refined by querying the system properties:

```
 if(System.getProperty("NO_COMPILE").equals("true")) {
    code
  }
```

This has the advantage that it can be easily set either from ANT or from Eclipse.

**EDIT**: Please remark that with if the code will actually be compiled and present in the .class files. Moreover, although querying system properties is more elegant, is done at runtime not at compile time hence is not quite inline with original requirement. The if(false) is on a 2nd tought better.

**EDIT2**: an even better solution I have just found: http://prebop.sourceforge.net/

Comment: putting it in a if(false) block does not work in eclipse. For example the following gives be compiler error (I have Project->Build Automatically "ON"): if (false){ intentional;} which means it is being compiled.

Comment: That's right - this is what I said in the first edit. Even the solution with static final WILL compile code. Eclipse SHOULD NOT give errors but warn you about "Dead code". If you have errors then it is probably something wrong in the block guarded by if(false)

Answer (score 1):

I can't even begin to imagine why this is an issue (as described) but I suspect the easiest thing to do is to grep for // in the code before you compile it (or commit it to your versioning repo).  I don't think there's anything in eclipse (if that's what you're using) to help you and I'm almost positive that java has no built in mechanism like the one you're describing in C.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this somewhere a while ago:

```
// /*
class SomeClass{
     int withSomeField;
     ..............
}
// */
```

And you can put the `//`s in and and remove them as necessary. It's probably multiline comments that would cause problem if they were in there, though.

Answer (score 1):

if(false) works well for me (using Eclipse).

Comment: Can you give an argument on *why* this is not compiled?

Comment: AFAIK, this is compiled. So you can't have code errors within the `if` block. I've tried the `static final boolean DONT_COMPILE = false` and then using `if (!DONT_COMPILE){}`. This too still compiles the code in the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use Java Preprocessor and I guess it will be better way than flags
http://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/
flags of course allow to cut and to add blocks on the compilation phase but preprocessor allows to make the process much more flexible

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to make the code conditional by preprocessing the source-code (as C does), use object oriented programming: use design patterns such as Strategy, and dependency injection, to make code conditional.

Answer (score -2):

There's not a Java-equivalent of the preprocessor's directive used in C/C++ languages.
Anyhow, you could do something similar using annotations or ANT, as briefly explained here

[Using annotations to add C like preprocessor directives](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1182231&tstart=-2)

or here

[How to do Conditional Compilation with Java](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/schaefa/archive/2005/01/how_to_do_condi.html)