# Java conditional imports

Tags: java

How to have conditional imports in Java like we have the `ifdefs` in C
This is what I intend to achieve

```
ifdef TEST
import com.google.mystubs.swing;
elif
import javax.swing.*;
endif
```

Comment: Possible subset of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526113/java-conditional-compilation-how-to-prevent-code-chunks-to-be-compiled

Answer (score 21):

You don't have conditional import with java

But you could conditionally use different classes with same name using fully qualified name

for example:

```
if(useSql){
  java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date()
}else{
  java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date()
}
```

Comment: This would only really be of benefit if both Dates implemented a common interface.

Comment: Say if both of those libraries were external JARs. Would the compiler include both of those JARs in the compiled code if `useSql` was `static final`?

Comment: Yes. it will. however you still need to provide it during runtime

Answer (score 5):

You could use a traditional if statement and then instead of importing do `Class.forName("example.ExampleClass")` That would return a `Class` object which you could then invoke `Class.newInstance()` on. It would allow you to avoid compile time errors for dependencies that may not exist as well as do something that's similar to conditional importing.

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 2):

We don't have conditional import in java

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for this at Java. 
Bear in mind that #IFDEF is done at pre-processor stage at C++ - No support in Java for that. 
What you can try and have is something like an annotation processor, prior to the days annotations were introduced in JDK 1.5. 
In addition, you can use annotations to be processed during compile time. 
[This](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/) blog provides some information.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Comment Preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor) supports prefix and postfix sections in result document and it is very useful to form class import section, you can place import string even in middle of your class

```
//#ifdef FLAG
//+prefix
import some.class.Clazz;
//-prefix
   Clazz.call();
//#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing this:

```
import com.test.example.interceptorModule
{
   example().intercepte();
}
```

I figured out that we can call the class using it's path like this

```
com.test.example.interceptorModule().intercepte()
```

so to import the above class conditionally you can do this:

```
if(!intercepting)
 {
   com.test.example.interceptorModule().intercepte()
 }
```

Comment: Can you show all your testing code for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is a valid idea, but you should use mocks instead. [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) is a great library for that.

The paradigm is a bit different, but you should look into unit testing with a mocking library and get an understanding of that, which will allow you to do what you're trying, in a better (in my opinion) way.