# Compiling to different targets Android

Tags: android, target

Our app is distributed from multiple markets and as the developer I need to make different code run for each of those targets, something like:

```
if (target == ROCK) do A;
else if (target == PAPER) do B;
```

and so on, does ADT/Eclipse support these kinds of stuff?

How should I go about doing it?

Comment: Do you mean as in different version of the sdk or as in different locations/carriers?

Comment: neither, i want to have my own defined targets, is that possible?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4526126/622391) says you can't, but there are other ways. Have a look at [this solution](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/schaefa/archive/2005/01/how_to_do_condi_1.html) which _"[uses] Ant's copy and filter feature to create the source with the different code in it"_.

Answer (score 1):

you can set in the res/values folder a parameter (e. g. string in strings.xml) to check for. This string can be parametered with the target (e. g. screensize in res/values-480x800).

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this, depending on what you want:

1. Multiple APKs, each with hardcoded options.
2. A single APK that executes code conditionally.

For approach 1, you can use [build flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) in gradle / Android Studio (I don't think ADT supports this). You can basically build multiple versions of a single APK choosing different source files in each. Then, in the Play Store, you can distribute these different files according to your criteria.

For approach 2, you have a few options:

1. For resources, you can [provide different files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) depending on Language and Region (or MCC).
2. For code, `getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry()` to get the country of the device or [`TelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperator%28%29) for the MCC

Answer (score 0):

once I had similar problem for J2ME development, [I just developed preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor), you can try to use it for Android projects