# android api parameter number changes. How to support it?

Tags: java, android

I am using a library from others, which i cannot change. 
Now I found one API has been changed.

Previous version 1:

```
int api_it(int a, int b)
```

The new version 2:

```
int api_it(int a, int b, int c, int d)
```

I was asked to **support both versions**. I thought I could use this (I am still using the previous jar file),

```
if( version == 1 )
    api_it(a, b);
else
    api_it(a,b,0,0);
```

There is the compile error for sure. I thought it not possible to include 2 versions of same library.

Is there any way to solve it? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think u`re looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/3940823/1615250 If correct answer check it. Ty

Answer (score 1):

Basically java doesn't support conditional compilation like , C++ does like in C++,

```
#define Version2
#ifdef Version2
  //Call version 2 function
#ifdef Version1
  //Call version 1 function
```

But there is one concept call Optimization you can use it following are some links that helps you on same.
[Java conditional compilation: how to prevent code chunks to be compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526113/java-conditional-compilation-how-to-prevent-code-chunks-to-be-compiled)

[Conditional compile](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=64)

[Conditional Compilation In Java](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ConditionalCompilationInJava)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I was not clear for the question. I need to check the target version at run-time. Finally, I solved it by java reflection.