# string literals - shared source file for C++, Java, Objective-C?

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, string-literals

Is there a way to have a single source file define compile-time string literals in both Java and C++ (and ideally also Objective-C) ?

For C++ and Objective-C it's relatively easy using `#if __OBJC__`:

```
#if __OBJC__
#define _str_literal_ @
#else
#define _str_literal_
#endif

#define MY_TOKEN _str_literal_"hello world"

#undef _str_literal_
```

But for C++ / Java I suspect some sort of code-generating tool would be required.

*Edited to reflect Dale's advice.*

Comment: Please don't use two leading underscores in your own code.  Those symbols are reserved for the compiler.

Comment: Write code to generate the definitions for each language? That lets you keep exactly one definitive source of the literals.

Comment: Even if such a mechanism existed (and it does not exist for C++ and Java), its use would be limited. Sooner or later your software may have to be translated into different languages, and then you'll need a more complex solution anyway.

Comment: Does Java support conditional compilation directives?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: No.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526113/java-conditional-compilation-how-to-prevent-code-chunks-to-be-compiled

Comment: @dalewilson - did not know; thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ChristianHackl - good point re more languages.

Comment: I guess a funky way of doing it would be to have the definitions in C++ and assign them to variables in Java via the JNI.