# Maven - Do not compile a specific test method within a test class

Tags: java, maven

You can skip **executing** the tests via command line by the following command:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

You can also skip **executing of a specific unit test** like that:

`mvn -Dtest=\!com.example.ExampleTest#testName install`

I know that you can also use the `maven.test.skip` property to skip **compiling** the tests

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Is there a way to skip **compiling of a specific unit test** from command line? In other words, I do not want a particular test to be included in a target folder (without deleting the test code, of course).

Comment: You could just comment out the Test annotation. `// @Test`.

Comment: I am implementing a script, which means that I want to get it done by command line. It is straightforward to do it manually

Comment: I do not understand your explanation.  If you want to disable just one test of many, have it in its own class then.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The problem is that I want to make this script as much programmatic as possible and exclude the manual work. I'm doing some research about mutation testing. Imagine that I run tests 100+ times on different sources, I cannot create own class for each case manually 100+ times... or comment out a line as you said. I want a command to be able to do that

Comment: I am using Pitest and unfortunately it does not have support to exclude one specific test when executing tests (like maven does with -Dtest param). It seems that only option for me is to add this feature to PIT tool

Comment: You may want to look into parameterized testing.  This allows running a single test on each entry of a large dataset and moves the configuration out of maven and into your testing framework.

Comment: If your current test framework does not support that, reconsider your choice of test framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude a test class from compilation by Maven you can add an `testExclude` to your `maven-compiler-plugin` declaration.

For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- use testExcludes to exclude a class from the src/test tree -->
      <testExcludes>
        <testExclude>/path/to/your/class</testExclude>
      </testExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Update** based on this:

> `Kote>` I'm looking to exclude a single/multiple unit test, not the whole class
>
> `glytching>` You want the class to be compiled and run by Surefire but you want the compiled form to exclude an individual test (i.e. a method) within that class?
>
> `Kote>` Yes

You can ...

- Tell Maven not to execute any tests by using `-DskipTests`.
- Tell Maven not to execute a specific test case by using `-Dtest=\!com.example.ExampleTest`.
- Tell Maven not to execute a specific test within a specific test case by using `-Dtest=\!com.example.ExampleTest#testName`.
- Tell Maven not to compile any classes in the test tree by using `-Dmaven.test.skip`.
- Tell Maven not to compile a specific class in the test tree by using `maven-compile-plugin::testExcludes`.

But you cannot tell Maven not to compile a specific **method** within a class.

It sounds like you need a [conditional compilation solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526113/java-conditional-compilation-how-to-prevent-code-chunks-from-being-compiled). Or perhaps you should edit the class before compilation. Either way, there's no built-in support for this in Maven (or in Java).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I'm looking to exclude a single/multiple unit test, not the whole class and also execute it from the command line. Sorry for confusion, I edited the question.

Comment: You want the class to be compiled and run by Surefire but you want the compiled form to exclude an individual test (i.e. a method) within that class?

Comment: Yes, I know it sounds weird, but if you're interested I can explain why I want to do that. 
But before that do you think it is possible?