# Exclude endpoints by creating dynamic jars in a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, endpoint

I have a multi module spring boot project. Each module has its own controller with N endpoints.
I would like to be able to create jar with different endpoints based on the profile used during the build, perhaps with Maven profiles.
Whereas I don't want to exclude a whole controller but only some controller endpoints.

I know that maybe this thing can be done using the spring profile. But with using spring profiles, it means that the jar would always have all the endpoints. I want to remove them completely and not "hide" them. Once the jar is created with a certain profile, the endpoints ignored by that profile must not be accessible.

Is there a possibility to do this or do I have to create separate branches?

Thank you

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you want to remove some methods (= endpoints) of a Java class (= controller) during compilation? That sounds a lot like conditional compilation and I don't know if that's possible in Java.

Comment: Exact. I want to have the ability to create jars with different endpoints using the same project. Without having to create different branches

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this then: [Java conditional compilation: how to prevent code chunks from being compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526113/1915448)