# Java (Eclipse) - Conditional compilation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, java-me, conditional-compilation

I have a java project that is referenced in j2me project and in android project.
In this project i would like to use conditional compilation.

Something like...

```
//#if android
...
//#endif

//if j2me
...
//#endif
```

I have been reading about this but i did not find anything useful yet.

Comment: Do you really able to develop one application for android and j2me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional Java compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922521/conditional-java-compilation)

Comment: not one app for both platforms ... i have a core project that is referenced in both j2me and android app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Antenna](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/) (there is a plugin for Eclipse, and you can use it with the Ant build system).
I'm using it in my projects in a way you've described and it works perfectly :)

EDIT: here is the example related to @WhiteFang34 solution that is a way to go:

**In your core project:**

```
//base class Base.java
public abstract class Base {
    public static Base getInstance() 
    {
        //#ifdef ANDROID
        return new AndroidBaseImpl();
        //#elif J2ME
        return new J2MEBaseImpl();
        //#endif
    }

    public abstract void doSomething();
}

//Android specific implementation AndroidBaseImpl.java
//#ifdef ANDROID
public class AndroidBaseImpl extends Base {
    public void doSomething() {
     //Android code
    }
}
//#endif

//J2ME specific implementation J2MEBaseImpl.java
//#ifdef J2ME
public class J2MEBaseImpl extends Base {
    public void doSomething() {
        // J2Me code
    }
}
//#endif
```

**In your project that uses the core project:**

```
public class App {

    public void something {
        // Depends on the preprocessor symbol you used to build a project
        Base.getInstance().doSomething();
    }
}
```

Than if you want to build for the Android, you just define *ANDROID* preprocessor symbol or *J2ME*  if you want to do a build for a J2ME platform...

Anyway, I hope it helps :)

Comment: i tested it and it works fine. In a single project. What i want is conditional IFs in core base code that is referenced from j2me and android project. How can i do that? Hope u get my point ...

Comment: Oh, I understand it now... you could use Antenna in combination with the Ant build system and than for specific target define something like USE_ANDROID in your build script that would result in rebuilding/pre-processing your base project to use Android specific code.

Comment: thanx man, sounds like a plan. If u can think of any sample out there please throw a bone ... im new to java so still having trouble with things that are basics for some of u ;)

Comment: thanx alot for taking your time and providing me with this sample. I understand the logic around this, i was just hoping there could be some way to get core project "to know" who is referencing it on build time. So switching define in ant settings in core project is the only way to go right?

Comment: just one more question .... can i implement two more core projects (one for j2me and one for android), define target in each of them and link files to core project where ant compiles depending on the target device?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you should consider creating interfaces around the logic that's specific to a profile (J2ME, Android or other in the future). Then create concrete implementations of your interface for each profile. Any common parts you could split out into an abstract base class for both implementations to extend. This way your logic for each profile is nicely separated for different concerns. For each profile just build the appropriate set of classes (you could separate them by package for example). It'll be easier to maintain, debug, test and understand in the long run.

Comment: thats an interesting solution. I will consider it. Im used to use pragma cc in C# so i figured it has to be similar in java (im new to java). I read that this could be achieved with ANT and WWYT, but i did not find any pros and cons for usage...

Comment: maybe some1 can demonstrate how i can use ANT for this? I have installed ANT plugin for eclipse and i want to do a simple test... a property of type string in my core lib to get a certain value if i run j2me or android project.

Comment: +1 That is what I had in mind when suggesting using the Ant build system with Antenna.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse [MTJ project](http://www.eclipse.org/mtj/) provides preprocessing support as [documented](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.mtj.doc.user/html/tasks/preprocessProject.html) . This support was mainly targeted for tackling fragmentation problems on JavaME. I have not tested the preprocessing support together with the Android tooling but it may just work.

Comment: thanx Gorkem. Probably i will use antenna, but will look into your proposal also.