# Include environment variable at compile time in Java

Tags: java

I have this scenario where I'm picking up an environment variable from the pipeline.

```
export SECRET = testing
```

#### In the library code

```
private static final String SECRET = System.getenv("SECRET");

public static String outputSecret() {
    return SECRET
}
```

I would like to compile the library and basically have the secret string as part of the library at compile time, so that the consumer of the library wouldn't need to care about the environment variable.

#### Consumer of library

```
Library.outputSecret(); // this would be testing
```

at the moment if I don't pass the environment variable everything is initialized to null. Is this achievable?

When building I use the command below. Unfortunately, the consumer of the library doesn't know what `SECRET` is.

```
export SECRET = testing
./gradlew clean build
```

Comment: Are you trying to load an environment variable from the build system *at runtime*? That's obviously not possible. If you are trying to generate a file at compile time that includes the parameter, that's possible, but it won't help you: The secret will still be in the compiled code, so you won't have achieved anything. You'll just need to specify the secret safely at runtime.

Comment: This can definitely be done using maven or gradle

Comment: @Nick Feel free to be more specific. You'll have to save the variable *somewhere* which will always include it in the build artifact.

Comment: Just a guess, but Nick likely meant filtering files to include desired `pom.xml` constants. But as you stated, you have to store it somewhere, and in this case it'd be in two places. @OP This sounds like a user configuration task, not something for the software itself to set up. Moreso it reads like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/): why do you need this? What are you hoping to solve by doing this? Environment variables are definitely not where I'd look first.

Comment: @Rogue You can use environment variable names in value references in a pom.xml (e.g. `${env.VARIABLE_NAME}`), so you can use them to configure filtering. Similar access is available in Gradle as well.

Comment: Is this your secret or theirs? Because if it's your secret, embedding a secret (such as an API key or authentication credentials) in a `.class` file is not hiding it. Any teenage script kiddie with a few minutes of time will be able to read that key, even in an obfuscated `.class` file.

Comment: I guess my that is my only option each consumer of the library would need to provide the secret. I was hoping to avoid that scenario.

Comment: Since there is no way you could possibly maintain the "secret" secret (with this idea) you might as well add in your library a properties file with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you have and what you want to achieve, but it seems like what you are looking for falls under the category of ***conditional compilation***, which consists of two parts:

- How to selectively compile different pieces of code based on some external variable, (which might not apply to you,) but most importantly:
- How to inject such an external variable into the compilation process. (Very much applies to you.)

Java out of the box does not support such a construct, and it has been a conscious decision of the team that developed java to not have such a construct. Their rationale is that without such a construct, every java compilation unit has one and only one way in which it can be interpreted, and there is merit in this.

Of course, for those who are hell-bent on nonetheless having such a construct, despite the fact that the language has explicitly chosen to not offer it, there exist workarounds.  You can perform a search for "java conditional compilation" or you can go directly to this Q&A: [Conditional Java compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1922521/773113)